# AngularFire: Getting the ID of Users Data from email in SimpleLogin

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to implement some simple using registration using Firebase through AngularFire and Angular.js. I'm using the SimpleLogin tool to manage the users. I can create users just fine.

```
  var firebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
  var simpleLogin = $firebaseSimpleLogin(firebaseRef);

  var firebaseUsersRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users');
  var firebaseUsers = $firebase(firebaseUsersRef);

  var myObject = {

    register: function(user) {
      var myDate = new Date().getTime();

      return simpleLogin.$createUser(
        user.email, user.password)
        .then(function(regUser) {
            var userInfo = {
                date: myDate,
                md5: regUser.md5_hash,
                firstname: user.firstname,
                lastname: user.lastname,
                email: user.email
              }
            firebaseUsers.$push(userInfo).then(function(ref) {
              userInfo.uid = ref.name();
              $rootScope.currentUser = userInfo;
            });
        }); //push user
    }, //register
```

Works like a charm. In order to get at this information when the user logs in, I've tried implementing an event handler on the $rootscope. I would like it to search through the uid that I stored and then get me record with the right user information.

```
$rootScope.$on('$firebaseSimpleLogin:login', function (e, authUser) {
  var query = $firebase(firebaseRef.startAt(authUser.uid).endAt(authUser.uid));
  console.log(query);
  $location.path('/meetings');
});
```

In order to use startAt and endAt, do I have to establish $priority. When I try, I get an error stating that I can't have any special characters. So that never works. I don't really care about how this data stored, I just want to get the index of the data so that I can retrieve the right user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Frank, I was able to figure out the right way to do this. In order to make my own users object searchable, I can use the uid from the simpleLogin object. So my register function works like this:

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
var simpleLogin = $firebaseSimpleLogin(firebaseRef);

var myObject = {
register: function(user) {
  var myDate = new Date().getTime();

  return simpleLogin.$createUser(user.email, user.password)
    .then(function(regUser) {
        var userInfo = {
            date: myDate,
            md5: regUser.md5_hash,
            firstname: user.firstname,
            lastname: user.lastname,
            email: user.email
          }

        firebaseUsers.$set(regUser.uid, userInfo);
    }); //add user
}, //register
} //my Object
```

Using set instead of push, I can store the uid from the registered user into the object and then pass along what I want to add as the second parameter. My database will now have the users organized by uid, which can be accessed via a url.

Then, when users log in, Firebase will throw up a login event along with the authenticated user, which I can catch and use to add the current user to the $rootScope that's accessible throughout my application.

```
 $rootScope.$on('$firebaseSimpleLogin:login', function (e, authUser) {
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/users/' + authUser.uid);
    var user = $firebase(ref).$asObject();

    user.$loaded().then(function() {
      $rootScope.currentUser = user;
    });

    $location.path('/meetings');
  });
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Frank.

Answer (score 2):

By using `$push` you tell Firebase to generate a key for you.

This is great for collections where you normally access all children at the same time. But that is not the case for your user info: you want to access the info for the current user.

So instead of using `$push` to add your user's info, I would use the `uid` of the user.

In the regular Firebase JavaScript API this can be accomplish with:

```
firebaseUsersRef.child(reguser.uid).set(userInfo);
```

The equivalent in AngularFire probably uses `$set`, but I don't think you have any need for that in your `$createUser` callback.

## Update

It looks like you're trying to add your info to the existing user node that Firebase creates for you. This is the example from that from the [Firebase documentation on storing user data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html):

```
  myRef.child('users').child(user.uid).set({
    displayName: user.displayName,
    provider: user.provider,
    provider_id: user.id
  });
```

You can see that they do access the user's node using `child(user.uid)` similar to what I proposed.

## Lessons

Two relatively small mistakes here as far as I can see:

1. when you use `push`/`$push`, you let Firebase generate the node name for you. In cases where there already is a globally unique ID (such as the `uid` of a user), you're often better off using that as the node name.
2. If you know the name of the node you want to retrieve, you don't need a query. You can simply access the node as `ref.child(user.uid)`.

Comment: Thanks Frank...That was very helpful. I suspected that my problem was with push, but I was bothered by having to index by the auth.id so that the record would become searchable. Your comment helped me figure out the direction I needed to go. I'll post what I did below.